# GreenDao reload an object when using IdentityScope != None

Tags: android, greendao

I have the case that I operate on some object I got from greenDao and in some cases I have to revert the changes. I only got this to work with IdentityScope.None - with some IdentityScope I found no way to do that - even refresh() which sounded promising was not bringing back the data from the database. Is there any way to do this with a IdentityScope?

Comment: Why did refresh not work?

Comment: dunno why - just saw the effect that the data was still the same - with IdentityScope.NONE I got the old data

Comment: There's a unit test for refresh: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoTest/src/de/greenrobot/daotest/entity/TestEntityTest.java What is different in your case?

Comment: thanks - I am investigating

Comment: I think I found the problem - I assumed that when I refresh an object, that all objects on that object are also refreshed - this does not seem to be the case. need to write an recursiveRefresh now - thanks for the feedback! When you put it as an answer I would acceppt it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The refresh(entity) method of a DAO does reload all entity values from the database. However, it operates on a single entity, not on a tree of entities.

Comment: What is the way to refresh the related entities from the current entity?